# How do I import my gmail email to outlook email in Ubuntu?

Tags: email, gmail, microsoft

I want to import my gmail emails to outlook email in Ubuntu. I do not have windows machine so I cannot follow the official document for importing emails into outlook. Is there a way I can import all my gmail email to outlook in Ubuntu ? Please help.

Comment: Are you accessing Outlook via a web browser or WINE?

Comment: I am accessing outlook via a web browser. I am using office 365 on browser.

Comment: If using Outlook, via the web, you should be able to setup an account, and logon to the gmail account, where it can store the email from gmail.

Comment: [Accessing Gmail accounts in Outlook 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-email-accounts-in-Outlook-on-the-web-Office-365-d7012ff0-924f-4f78-8aca-c3912d886c4d) - Try this.